# How to create a form where you can select multiple recipients, based on a list of website users?

Tags: plugins, forms, email

First of all, I'm not a professional developer but I do have basic programming knowledge and experience. I apologize in case someone pulls their hairs at my low knowledge about wordpress development.

This is the use case I wish to achieve:

1. A user comes to my website and enters a contact form.
2. In the form the user can select a specific value, for example COUNTRY.
3. The COUNTRY value is also a value assigned to users registered on the website.
4. Finally the user sends his e-mail at the end of the form. Based on the selected country, I want the email to be sent to all Users with this tag.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: There's multiple ways to go about doing this - both with a plugin or writing some custom code.  I'd write the form and the `wp_mail()` function myself and then add a 'country' assignment field to the `user_meta` - then, when the users selects a country, I'd populate the recipient aspect of the `wp_mail()` with the user emails of those that have that country in their `user_meta`.  Going further, I'd make the dropdown of countries only include those that already exist in the `user meta` records.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.